# Spring Boot invalid CSRF token on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, csrf, csrf-token

I have app with backend written in Java (Spring Boot) exposing REST API and frontend in Javascript (React). Requests are handled correctly on localhost (even when running the backend with `heroku local web`, however when I deployed the API server on Heroku, any request which is not GET will fail with 403 - Forbidden error. Investigating the logs I found out the issue is in CSRF token being supposedly invalid:

```
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288650+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.288 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288652+00:00 app[web.1]: Host: xxx-server.herokuapp.com
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288653+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection: close
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288653+00:00 app[web.1]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288654+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288654+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288654+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288655+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288655+00:00 app[web.1]: Origin: https://xxx-client.herokuapp.com
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288656+00:00 app[web.1]: Dnt: 1
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288656+00:00 app[web.1]: Referer: https://xxx-client.herokuapp.com/login
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288657+00:00 app[web.1]: Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=d6392331-6f4f-4563-9d39-dd0fc55f7a8c; JSESSIONID=858AAFEE26679A572B991C091B4D15A7
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288658+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Id: 6f81547f-0699-4ecd-9ba3-b550431e6574
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288658+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-For: 213.175.51.1
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288658+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Proto: https
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288659+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Port: 443
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288659+00:00 app[web.1]: Via: 1.1 vegur
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288659+00:00 app[web.1]: Connect-Time: 1
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288660+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Start: 1593679235264
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288660+00:00 app[web.1]: Total-Route-Time: 0
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288660+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Length: 41
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288661+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-07-02T08:40:35.288661+00:00 app[web.1]: {"username":"user","password":"password"}]
2020-07-02T08:40:35.289207+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.289 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: XSRF-TOKEN=d6392331-6f4f-4563-9d39-dd0fc55f7a8c; JSESSIONID=858AAFEE26679A572B991C091B4D15A7
2020-07-02T08:40:35.294663+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.294 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 858AAFEE26679A572B991C091B4D15A7
2020-07-02T08:40:35.295067+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.295 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve   : Incoming request /api/login with originalRemoteAddr [10.36.40.162], originalRemoteHost=[10.36.40.162], originalSecure=[false], originalScheme=[http], originalServerName=[xxx-server.herokuapp.com], originalServerPort=[80] will be seen as newRemoteAddr=[213.175.51.1], newRemoteHost=[213.175.51.1], newSecure=[true], newScheme=[https], newServerName=[xxx-server.herokuapp.com], newServerPort=[443]
2020-07-02T08:40:35.295285+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.295 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /api/login
2020-07-02T08:40:35.295437+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.295 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2020-07-02T08:40:35.295587+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.295 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2020-07-02T08:40:35.296468+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.296 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/login at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-07-02T08:40:35.296772+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.296 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/login at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-07-02T08:40:35.296861+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.296 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/login at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-07-02T08:40:35.297193+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.297 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/login at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
2020-07-02T08:40:35.307430+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.307 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-07-02T08:40:35.335515+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.335 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/login at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2020-07-02T08:40:35.336779+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.336 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2020-07-02T08:40:35.336875+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.336 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for https://xxx-server.herokuapp.com/api/login
2020-07-02T08:40:35.411867+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/login" host=xxx-server.herokuapp.com request_id=6f81547f-0699-4ecd-9ba3-b550431e6574 fwd="213.175.51.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=145ms status=403 bytes=702 protocol=https
2020-07-02T08:40:35.370981+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.370 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-07-02T08:40:35.383898+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-02 08:40:35.383 DEBUG 4 --- [io-12333-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
```

As you can see, the XSRF-TOKEN cookie (which works on localhost) is there. Here are my security settings:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(Mappings.API_ROOT_USERS + "/current")
        .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
        .logoutUrl(Mappings.API_ROOT + "/logout")
        .deleteCookies(Constants.JWT_COOKIE_NAME)
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.addFilterBefore(jsonUsernamePasswordFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```

How could I fix this?

**UPDATE:** I tried to manually edit the request and copied the value from XSRF-TOKEN cookie to X-XSRF-TOKEN header and the request passed through. So the issue is probably that client (React/axios) can't see the cookie and set the header. I also can't see any client cookies in Storage tab of Developer tools when in Heroku deployed version (I can on localhost). Can it have something to do with herokuapp.com being listed in Public Suffix list? (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com)

Comment: *So the issue is probably that client (React/axios) can't see the cookie and set the header.*
Have you set the HTTP-only flag to `false` to let the client read the cookie?